# Saving a path to an element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, dom-events

I have a listener for a 'keydown' event, once the listener is called I want to be able to highlight that element forever (future reloads).

How can I extract the path to the element from the listener? (It may or may not have an id)

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  const keyName = event.key;
  if(keyName === 's')
      //save path to element here
});
```

Comment: Could you include the code you have tried so far in your question?

Comment: @Tholle just added

Comment: @kambi Can we assume that the HTML never changes? (also, that code isn't an attempt to solve this question... ;)) The basic idea is to go up the tree until you hit something with an id and each time, note which n-th child the current element is.

Comment: So does the element have a specific class , id, etc? Answer depends on what is available.

Comment: @ChrisG yes it never changes

Comment: @epascarello we don't know, it can be any element in any webpage, we want to come up with a general solution.

Comment: @kambi See text I added to my previous comment. Btw, the code above doesn't determine an element, does it?

Comment: @ChrisG yes what you wrote makes sense, I'm looking for the best way to do it, I guess there's a module for that. the code above is just an example. thanks

Comment: So than you need to walk the tree back counting prev siblibgs and parents and build with the index. Or use classes, ids etc.